# How to compare 2 fields in django 2.1?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Models.py**
   This is my model class where i have 2 tables .on each table we have a field called label.My question is that how will i compare the 2 labels and return values to a new field (returnlabel)

```
 class Server(models.Model):
     label = models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True)  #compare this
     upload1 = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
     Image1 = models.TextField(upload1, null=True)

class Android(models.Model):
     label=models.TextField(max_length=200,null=True) #with this
     imagestring=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
     returnlabel=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True) #return to this
```

**Serializers Class**

```
   class FoodSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
       model=Server
       fields=('url','label','Image1','upload1')

   class AndroidSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = Android
    fields = ('label', 'imagestring', 'returnlabel')
```

**Views**

```
 class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class =FoodSerializers

class Androids(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset =Android.objects.all()
   serializer_class = AndroidSerializers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Try Like this:

```
class AndroidSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    return_label =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Android
        fields = ('label', 'imagestring', 'return_label')

    def get_return_label(self, obj):
        queryset = Server.objects.filter(
            label=obj.label)
        queryset_serializer = FoodSerializers(
            queryset, many=True, read_only=True)
        return queryset_serializer.data
```

Comment: gives me an error of  HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

Comment: Sorry, where are you using [hyperlinkedidentityfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield)? Its not in my answer

Comment: It works but it seems to show all the objects of Model Server

Comment: if  the label of all the server objects is same as the android object(which you are serializing), then it will show all serializer.

Comment: Thankyou..jus one quick question any idea how to us push notification like sending the return_label back to my android device

Comment: Sorry, not sure about how to do that. But there are some libraries like: https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications

Comment: Sorry to bother u once again ..i have now created another field in Server know as list and i want to store it in a list.any ideas?

Comment: Hi, No worries. But I could not understand your question. If you can ask a question on stackoverflow with details on codes and how you want to store, we will help you to solve it. Thanks

Comment: hi.how can i use this code in my views? like instead of the serializer class